# What does "NOS-production: no" mean?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, bootloader, google-pixel-3-xl

I recently bought a refurbished unlocked Pixel 3 XL to replace my aging, cracked, broken one of the same model. It came with the bootloader unlocked so I decided to lock it because I didn't like the warning message every time it booted and noticed that in the Fastboot menu of the bootloader it shows:

Secure boot: PRODUCTION
NOS-production: no

I'm concerned about that NOS-production setting; has this device been tampered with? My old Pixel 3 XL shows yes there as well as all other screenshots I see of the bootloader on other P3XL's - they all say yes instead of no. I used flash.android.com and completely flashed the phone to the latest April Android 11 firmware but it still shows no. I can't find any documentation of what that could mean. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: In my opinion should should name the vendor so that other people can avoid it (and I would send back the device and reclaim the money). That an refurbished phone has an unlocked bootloader is pretty unusual and may indicate that the device may originiate from illegal sources (device theft).